# Angular 2 - ngModelChange firing onBlur and onFoucs of input box in IE-11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have an input field with ngModel and ngModelChange

```
<input [(ngModel)]="searchJobs" (ngModelChange)="loadSuggestedJobs()">
```

In Firefox and Chrome, the function is being called only when the text in the input box is changing. But in IE, it is being called on focus and blur of the input box too.

Note: I've used (change) instead, but that doesn't fire with each key press.

Comment: `(ngModel)` and `(ngModelChange)` are the same output bindings. I don't think that is causing your issue.

Comment: have you tried with `(keyup)="loadSuggestedJobs()"`?

Comment: @camaron There are some exceptions with keyup.
Ex: If I paste something with mouse, keyup won't fire.

Comment: @sunnyiitkgp because that is another event, `onpaste` in that case, Check if there's an event for that in angular, should be `(paste)`.

Comment: @camaron Thanks for your suggestion. I'll have to consider multiple cases like this... Am checking if I can get a better alternative.